# in VI and man command, how to exactly match a string?

Tags: linux, vi, man

in VI and man command, how to exactly match a string? I don't know how to exact match a string~

Comment: Do you mean match "by" in "something by something" but not in "something bytes this"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press <kbd>/</kbd> and enter the [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for the string you want to match, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a single word, you can use `/\<word\>`.